# Android VirtualDisplay.release() not releasing the display

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaprojection

I'm using android `MediaProjection` for taking screenshot. The projection needs to be stopped after taking screenshot and `virtual display` should be released but `VirtualDisplay.release()` is not releasing the display. Here is the code to create display.

```
startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

        sMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

        // display metrics
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        mDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
        mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        mDisplay.getSize(size);
        mWidth = size.x;
        mHeight = size.y;

        // register media projection stop callback
        sMediaProjection.registerCallback(new MediaProjectionStopCallback(), mHandler);

        // register orientation change callback
        mOrientationChangeCallback = new OrientationChangeCallback(this);
        if (mOrientationChangeCallback.canDetectOrientation()) {
            mOrientationChangeCallback.enable();
        }


        // start capture reader
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 1);
        mVirtualDisplay = sMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAP_NAME, mWidth, mHeight, mDensity, VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS, mImageReader.getSurface(), null, mHandler);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener(), mHandler);
    }
}
```

To stop the projection, I call `sMediaProjection.stop();` and here is my `MediaProjectionStopCallback` implementation.

```
private class MediaProjectionStopCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.e("ScreenCapture", "stopping projection.");
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                if (mVirtualDisplay != null) {
                    mVirtualDisplay.release();
                    Log.e("Virtual Display", "Released");
                }
                if (mImageReader != null)
                    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);    
                if (mOrientationChangeCallback != null)
                    mOrientationChangeCallback.disable();
                sMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(MediaProjectionStopCallback.this);

                DisplayManager disp = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE);
                Display[] allDisplays = disp.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
                Log.e(TAG + "-Display", "Display Count  " + allDisplays.length);
                for (Display dl : allDisplays) {
                    Log.e(TAG + "-Display", "Display name: " + dl.getName() + " Display id: " + dl.getDisplayId());
                }
            }
        });

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Projection Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the logcat.

```
03-02 14:52:55.925    8264-8732/codistan.pk.squeeze_me E/ScreenCapture﹕ stopping projection.
03-02 14:52:55.925    8264-8732/codistan.pk.squeeze_me E/Virtual Display﹕ Released
03-02 14:52:55.925    8264-8732/codistan.pk.squeeze_me E/codistan.pk.squeeze_me.ScreenCaptureActivity-Display﹕ Display Count  1
03-02 14:52:55.935    8264-8732/codistan.pk.squeeze_me E/codistan.pk.squeeze_me.ScreenCaptureActivity-Display﹕ Display name: screencap Display id: 1
```

I have double checked, the above `onStop` method is properly called as can be seen in the logcat. After releasing the display in `onStop` when I check the available displays, the virtual display is still listed as an available display. `It affects the phone display and graphics and I can't play any video and the issue remains even after uninstalling the app untill I restart the phone.` I have checked this link [Android virtual display release does not remove display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718862/android-virtual-display-release-does-not-remove-display) and searched a lot but nothing found helpful. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Actually release call will be queued and will be processed in the event queue. try dumping surfaceflinger after some times you called release on virtual display

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Please find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823544/call-release-did-not-work-after-creating-virtual-display

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
if (mOrientationChangeCallback != null) {
    mOrientationChangeCallback.disable();
}
if (mVirtualDisplay != null) {
    mVirtualDisplay.release();
}
if (mMediaProjection != null) {
    mMediaProjection.stop();
}
if (mImageReader != null) {
    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
    mImageReader.close();
}
```